# php unserialize with private member

Tags: php, serialization

so based on definition the private numbers in a class is prefixed with the class name when being serialized. this is causing a problem for me that i want to be able to serialize/save/unserialize an exact object back, hwoever what php does is to give me an other varialbe of classname+variableName for private numbers.

is there any way i can easily unserialize back the private members?

thanks,

Comment: this should happen automatically with unserialize. Can you provide an example with the error happening?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about the internals of serialization unless your class inmplements the [`Serializable`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface or has [`__wakeup` and `__sleep`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) methods.

For example:

```
class Foo {
   private $Secret = "Private (init)";

   public $FooSecret = "Public (init)";

   function setSecret($secret) {
      $this->Secret = $secret;
   }
   function getSecret() {
      return $this->Secret;
   }
}

$bar = new Foo();
$bar->setSecret("Private (after serialize / unserialize)");
$bar->FooSecret = "Public (after serialize / unserialize)";
var_dump(unserialize(serialize($bar)));
```

Even though you've got a potential name clash between "FooSecret" and "Secret", PHP knows what to do and gives you:

```
object(Foo)#2 (2) {
  ["Secret":"Foo":private]=>
  string(39) "Private (after serialize / unserialize)"
  ["FooSecret"]=>
  string(38) "Public (after serialize / unserialize)"
}
```